# How to create a collection class that is able to manage and create objects of a certain class and its subclasses with proper type hints

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I have a class `Thing` that represents some thing and a class `ThingCollection` that manages a collection of such things. Like this:

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, a: int) -> None:
        self.a = a


class ThingCollection:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.things = []

    # ...

    def load(self, things_to_load) -> None:
        # Simplified, would maybe load from a file
        self.things = [Thing(**x) for x in things_to_load]
```

This can be used like this:

```py
coll = ThingCollection()
coll.load([{"a": 12}])
```

Now, I'd like to have subclasses of `Thing`s and manage those with the same `ThingCollection`. Like this:

```py
class ExtendedThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b


class ThingCollection2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.things = []

    # ...

    def load(self, things_to_load, which_class) -> None:
        self.things = [which_class(**x) for x in things_to_load]
```

This works fine:

```py
coll2 = ThingCollection2()
coll2.load([{"a": 12, "b": 13}], ExtendedThing)
print(coll2.things[0].b)
```

However, if I want to add type hints, the type checker complains. I.e., changing the signature of `load` to:

```py
    def load(self, things_to_load, which_class: Type[Thing]) -> None:
```

will lead to a complaint of `Cannot access member "b" for type "Thing" Member "b" is unknown` for the print statement above.

My questions:

1. What are alternative approaches that resolve this problem? One would be to also subclass the `ThingCollection` to, e.g., `ExtendedThingCollection`, but that feels clumsy and redundant.
2. What are pros and cons of the different approaches other than related to the type hint problem above?
3. What would be the right terminology to ask the question I'm asking? Are there design patterns that are relevant with regard to this question?

Comment: You should put some thought into what you're trying to accomplish here. When you have a collection on `Thing` type objects, you're only promising that each of those objects will have the property `a`: you say nothing about `b`. If you expect each of those objects to also implement `b` then you should add `b` to `Thing` itself.